# I want to call function on double click in angular 8

Tags: angular

I am using angular cli 8 and i want to trigger event on double click. Is there any built in method exist in angular?

I am doing in this way

```
<p >
  Note: Double click to increase counter
</p>
<button [(ng-dblclick)]="count = count + 1" >asad</button>
<h1>{{count}}</h1>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events

Comment: The syntax for event-binding is `(event)="..."`, not `[(event)]`="...". And standard DOM events don't start with `ng-`. The event name is `dblclick`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To perform events on double click of a button in Angular you can follow below syntax:

```
<button (dblclick)="doubleClick($event)">Double Click</button>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, There's an inbuilt method for double click

```
<div (dblclick)="doubleClicked(element)"></div>
```

But it won't work on mobiles and tablets

For that there's a work around

```
touchtime=0;
singleClick(){
    if (this.touchtime === 0) {
          this.touchtime = new Date().getTime();
        } else {
          if (new Date().getTime() - this.touchtime < 400) { <-- time between two clicks to be considered as double click
            this.doubleClicked(row);
            this.touchtime = 0;
          } else {
            this.touchtime = new Date().getTime();
          }
        }
}
```

Hope it helps!