# how to perform action on double click on a button using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, double-click, right-click

Using this I am checking for a right click on my button. How can I check for a double click on my button?

```js
app.directive('rightClick', function ($parse, $mdMenu) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var fn = $parse(attrs.rightClick);
        element.on('contextmenu', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            scope.$apply(function () {
                fn(scope, { $event: event });
            });
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<button right-click="$mdMenu.open($event)" id="{{element.id}}">
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128708/i-want-to-call-function-on-double-click-in-angular-8

Comment: @AdamBasha that not helpful that was angular 8 I am using angular js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try listening for the [`dblclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) event!

html

```
<button double-click="$ctrl.alertClick()" id="test">{{$ctrl.name}}</button>
```

js

```
window.app.directive('doubleClick', function ($parse) {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var fn = $parse(attrs.doubleClick);
    console.log(attrs.doubleClick);
    element.on('dblclick', function (event) {
      console.log('click');
      event.preventDefault();
      scope.$apply(function () {
        fn(scope, { $event: event });
      });
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  };
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-sra5ds)